# how do I change baud rate for bluesmirf without connecting to pc?

Tags: arduino, bluetooth, baudrate, sparkfun

Hi I have the sparkfun bluetooth mate silver. I am trying to start working on control via bluetooth for my Arduino. Only thing is I need to set the baud rate for the bluetooth mate, all guides I can find on the net show how to change it via pc. I do not have bluetooth connectivity on my PC. Is there a way to do it via the Arduino?

Comment: I suppose that obtaining a $2 USB Bluetooth radio is not an option?

Comment: not today. I will eventually

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change the Baud rate on the BlueSmirf, you will need to enter Command mode. To enter Command mode, you need to send "$$$" through the serial port connection. This can be done from a PC using a terminal program or from the Arduino.

Since you want to do this from the Arduino, you will need to write a little bit of code to parse the responses from the BlueSmirf so you can automate the steps necessary to change the Baud rate.

1. Send "$$$" - Enter Command Mode
2. Wait for "CMD" - Acknowledge in Command Mode
3. Send "SU,96" - Change Baud rate to 9600
4. Wait for "AOK" - Acknowledge command
5. Send "R,1" - Reboot device to use new setting

All the commands are documented in the [RN-42 AT Command Set](http://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Wireless/Bluetooth/rn-bluetooth-um.pdf)